# Copy xAct expression to LaTeX

Tags: latex, xact

How can I copy an xAct expression to LaTex? Using the usual command TeXForm[] gives the xAct structure, I would like to get the printed form. For example

$$
\text{TeXForm}[\nabla_a\phi\nabla^a\phi]
$$

gives

\text{CD}(-a)(p()) \text{CD}(-a)(p())

which is how I defined my tensors.

Comment: Thanks for the example, I've never used xAct before, but I have it installed, how would I go about having $\nabla_a\phi\nabla^a\phi$ defined in the first place?  Which subpackage(s) do I need to load, and what commands do I need to enter in order to have it as an object I can try to act on?

Comment: The basic commands you need to defined this expression are: $\\$
<< xAct`xTensor`
DefManifold[M4, 4, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l}]
DefMetric[-1, metric[-a, -b], CD, PrintAs -> "g"]    %CD here refers to the covariant derivative%
DefTensor[p[], M4, PrintAs -> "\[phi]"]  $p  is the scalar field%
and the expression above will be 
(CD[-a]@p[] CD[a]@p[])

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This imports the package and defines the variables,

```
<< xAct`xTensor`;

DefManifold[M4, 4, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l}] ;
DefMetric[-1, metric[-a, -b], CD, PrintAs -> "g"];
DefTensor[p[], M4, PrintAs -> "ϕ"];
```

This is your expression,

```
test = (CD[-a]@p[] CD[a]@p[])
```

[image]

Let's look at all the various forms there are of this expression,

```
Through[{TraditionalForm, TeXForm, InputForm, FullForm, StandardForm}[test]]
```

[image]

It seems that all forms except `StandardForm` see `test` as `CD[-a][p[]]CD[a][p[]]`  So we need to apply `StandardForm` and **then** `TeXForm`:

```
TeXForm@StandardForm@test
(* \left(\triangledown _a\phi
   \right) \left(\triangledown
   ^a\phi \right) *)
```

Or, evaluated in $\TeX$,

$$\left(\triangledown _a\phi
   \right) \left(\triangledown
   ^a\phi \right) $$