# Converting tensorial expressions in xAcT to LaTeX

Tags: latex, xact

I'm trying to convert tensorial expressions from xAct to LaTeX format using the TeXForm command. This seems to work fine when using covariant derivatives (As in [Copy xAct expression to LaTeX](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114225/copy-xact-expression-to-latex)). However, this seems to change when employing curvature invariants such as $R_{a}^{\ \ b}{}_c^{\ \ d}R^{a}_{\ \ b}{}^c_{\ \ d}$. In this case, evaluating $$\texttt{TeXForm@StandardForm@RiemannCD[-a, b, -c, d] RiemannCD[a, -c, b, -d]}$$
yields

[image]

Do you know how to avoid the array command and produce a similar output as in the previous link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xAct contains a full package dedicated to converting tensor expressions into LaTeX, called TexAct, and I'd recommend using that instead of the general TeXForm.

For example, in your case:

```
<< xAct`xTensor`
<< xAct`TexAct`

DefManifold[M, 4, {a, b, c, d}]
DefMetric[-1, g[-a, -b], CD]

expr = RiemannCD[-a, -b, -c, d] RiemannCD[a, c, b, -d];

In[]:= TexPrint[%]
Out[]= "R[\\nabla]_{abc}{}^{d} R[\\nabla]^{acb}{}_{d}"
```

If you want to change the name of the Riemann tensors use

```
PrintAs[RiemannCD] ^= "R";

In[]:= TexPrint[expr]
Out[]= "R_{abc}{}^{d} R^{acb}{}_{d}"
```

If your expressions are very large then look at the documentation of TexBreak on how to break the single-line TeX output into several lines. Note also the commands TexPort to send the result to a file and TexView to visualize the output.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jose. I was not aware of the existence of TexAct and it is useful for all my purposes.